Azure Logic App limit max wainting runs - What happens if limit exceded?
I have an Azure Logic App (Standard) to process files. The LA will be triggered by a Blob Stroage Trigger (InApp) and send the filecontent to an REST-Interface. To prevent the REST-Interface from a overload, I would like to limit the logic App with the following parameters:

Runtime.Trigger.MaximumRunConcurrency = 50
Runtime.Trigger.MaximumWaitingRuns = 100

What will happen if the MaximumWaitingRuns is exceedet and another event is fired by the Blob Storage?
Will the event be skipped and I miss that file?

It mentioned as below in MS Documentation as below

When the number of waiting instances reaches this limit, the Azure Logic Apps engine no longer accepts new workflow instances to run. Request and webhook triggers return 429 - Too many requests errors, and recurring triggers start skipping polling attempts.

Change waiting runs limit
